# Probability that $x_i<p<x_j$ given $X={x_1,\cdots,x_n}$ and $P(p=x_k)=1/n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> For list $X={x_1,\cdots,x_n}$ of $n$ elements with an unknown ordering. A pivot $p$ is selected from $X$ uniformly at random. Find the probability that two given elements $x_i$ and $x_j$ will be in different partitions of the list with respect to the pivot $p$ ?

We have an $n$ element list $X={x_1,\cdots,x_n}$ in which we have no idea about the ordering of its elements. Now, a pivot is selected uniformly at random from $X$, ie., $P(p=x_k)=1/n$ for all $i=1$ to $n$. We need to find the probability that for any elements $x_i,x_j\in X$, it is $x_i<p<x_j$ or $x_j<p<x_i$. We can instead start with finding the probability that $x_i<p$ for all possible $p$.

Lets sort the list in ascending order to form $X'=\{x'_1,\cdots,x'_n\}$ which won't alter the probability as $p$ is chosen uniformly random. If $p=x'_1$ then there are no elements less than $p$, if $p=x'_2$ then there is only one element less than $p$, if $p=x'_3$ then there are 2 elements less than $p$, and so on. Therefore,

\begin{align}
P(x'_k<p\text{ for a randomly chosen }p)&=\frac{1}{n}.\frac
{(0+1+2+\cdots+(n-1))}{n}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}.\frac{(n-1)n}{2n}=\frac{n-1}{2n}
\end{align}
Similarly,
\begin{align}
P(x'_k>p\text{ for a randomly chosen }p)=\frac{n-1}{2n}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\implies P(x'_i<p<x'_j)=P(x'_i<p).P(x'_j>p)=\frac{(n-1)^2}{4n^2}
\end{align}
and the required probability is $\frac{2(n-1)^2}{4n^2}=\frac{(n-1)^2}{2n^2}$.

Am I thinking it in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of calculating the probability you can assume they are ordered in increasing order.  With $n$ numbers, the number of pairs one can select is $n(n-1)/2$.  If you pick the pivot $p$ to be $x_i$ (for some $i$), then there are $(i-1)*(n-i)$ pairs that have the pivot strictly between the two values.  Now just sum this expression over $i$ (from 1 to $n$) and divide by $n$.

Comment: you mean divide by $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ not $n$ right?

Comment: Yes sorry to be clear: $${1\over n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} {{(i-1)(n-i)}\over{(n(n-1)/2)}}.$$  The term for $i$ is the probability that the pivot will be (strictly) between the randomly chosen $x$'s.  Then you're just averaging those probabilities to get the overall probability.

Comment: Then simplifying to $(n-2)/(3n)$ I believe.